# Inline heading with background color using @font-face - not working on Mac in either Safari or FF

Tags: css, macos, firefox, safari, font-face

I have an inline heading (`h1`) with a background-color on the heading, but on Mac OS in both safari and Firefox it does not seem to stretch around the font. With a websafe font it works fine. Line height is set according to the font-size.

Any suggestions?

See visual expamle:
http://www.flickr.com/photos/hegerokenes/5038724235/

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FedraMonoStd-Medium';
    src: url('fonts/fedramonostd-medium-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/fedramonostd-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/fedramonostd-medium-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/fedramonostd-medium-webfont.svg#webfontNCPrZ83i') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }


h1 {
    font-size: 22px;
    background-color: #999895;
    line-height: 38px;
    display: inline;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px;
    }
```

Comment: For kicks, try adding a height to the h1 tag

Comment: post your css please, seems easy to solve

Comment: Changing it to block wil only make a solid box around all the text. I want to have one "box" around each line.

Comment: Too bad I don't have a mac to try something... Did you try with a different `font-face` ? with `display: inline-block` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try a little more padding, this should work without messing up the line-height. say

```
padding: 12px 3px 3px 3px;
```

at least it did with the font i was using...

Comment: I ended up adding padding on the text, but had to do some nasty JS operating system sniffing, since this only was an issue on mac, and the extra padding showed (coorectly, like extra padding) on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try floating  left or `display:inline-block` instead, so it can be "blocky".